# How to make the second list item to be deleted once,not twice?

Tags: javascript

everyone.I have a question for javascript problem:
the second list item  Jello always  clicked twice to be deleted
in my html:

```
<ul id="Delete">

    <li class="bold red" random="23">
        <span>Notebook</span>
        <button onclick="myfunction()">Delete</button>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span>Jello</span>
        <button onclick="myfunction()">Delete</button>
    </li>
     <li>
     <span>Spinach</span>
         <button onclick="myfunction()">Delete</button>
    </li>
     <li>
        <span>Rice</span>
        <button onclick="myfunction()">Delete</button>
    </li>

 <li>
      <span>Birthday Cake</span>
     <button onclick="myfunction()">Delete</button>

    </li>

     <li>
         <span>Candles</span>
      <button onclick="myfunction()">Delete</button>
    </li>
```

in my js:

```
function myfunction(){

var Deletelist = document.getElementById("Delete");
Deletelist.removeChild(Deletelist.childNodes[1]);
```

}

I want the second and third list item and so on to be clicked one time to  be deleted.
Is there any improve ways to my code?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but maybe try using `ondblclick="myFunction()"` instead of regular `onClick`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just attach an event handler to every button, and delete the corresponding list item when the button is clicked.

```js
[...document.getElementsByTagName('button')].forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('click', () =>
    el.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(el.parentNode)));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="bold red" random="23">
    <span>Notebook</span>
    <button>Delete</button>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span>Jello</span>
    <button>Delete</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Spinach</span>
    <button>Delete</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Rice</span>
    <button>Delete</button>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span>Birthday Cake</span>
    <button>Delete</button>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span>Candles</span>
    <button>Delete</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks.It worked.But i don't understand what is el mean?and what is => Symbol to do ? and parentNode?What is that?Sorry,I am a beginner

Comment: `el` refers to the button element. The `=>` symbol denotes an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) selects and element's parent element. So in this case, I use `el.parentNode.parentNode` to get a reference to the list, and `el.parentNode` to get a reference to the list item.